# Como comparar y saber si un texto especifico esta en una cadena de texto PHP

Tags: php

lo que pasa es que quiere hacer un if que compare si en un texto esta la palabra EMPRESAS pero no se como hacer la comparación en php, se como hacerlo en javascript pero necesito hacerlo desede php.

Esto fue lo que hice

```
 if ($info['programa_uvi'] !== 'EMPRESAS') {
 echo "Si es diferente de EMPRESAS " . $tecnico;
 }
```

La cadena que trae $info es "PROFESIONAL EN ADMINISTRACION DE EMPRESAS"

Comment: Considera agregar una muestra de `$info`

Comment: Listo ya lo edite

Comment: La función [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strpos.php) puede servirte.

Comment: O si usas la versión 8 de PHP, entonces considera usar [str_contains](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta parte de tu código:

```
if ($info['programa_uvi'] !== 'EMPRESAS') {
```

No te va a funcionar para encontrar el resultado esperado, pues evaluará el contenido completo de la clave `programa_uvi` contra el texto *EMPRESAS*.

Dependiendo con que versión trabajes desde PHP 8, tenemos la función [**`str_constains`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) la cual nos ayuda a determinar si un *string* contiene un *substring* dado.

Si existe dicho string retorna `true` y en caso contrario retornará `false`.

Entonces la implementación puede quedar de esta forma:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

$array = ["clave" => "hola EMPRESA"];

function encuentraPalabra(array $conjuntoValores): string 
{
    if (!str_contains($conjuntoValores["clave"], "EMPRESA")) {
        return "No existe";
    }
    return "Existe";
}

echo encuentraPalabra($array);
```